# Error while submitting a job with Hadoop 2.6.0 on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm working on a Java project running with Hadoop 0.20.1 and I'm trying to migrate to Hadoop 2.6.0. Once I've changed the corresponding Hadoop jar files in the project, I obtain the following error when submitting a job:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
```

I've read it could be a problem related to Hadoop binaries, but I've built them myself, placed them in "c:\hadoop\bin" and the environment variable HADOOP_HOME has the right value.

I'm running my project on Eclipse, on a machine with Windows 7 64 bits and Java 8.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using standalone mode, pseudo distributed mode, or connecting to a cluster? 

check your installation by running the hadoop examples. Running hadoop on windows outside of standalone mode is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: I intend to use standalone mode. I've placed this in my mapred-site.xml with that purpose: "<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name><value>local</value>". I will download hadoop examples to make sure the installation is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved my problem. I had Java 8 32 bits installed instead of the 64 bits version. I installed the right version and Hadoop jobs submitted perfectly.